# Which is better - multiple joins to the same table or filtering in a case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where the fields can have different values depending on what one field is.  If ufd.table_code = 'case' then ufd.user_field_data_01 = member id, but if ufd.table_code = 'appe' then ufd.user_field_data_01 = appeal id.

I usually do this:

```
select UfdCase.user_field_data_01
      ,UfdAppe.user_field_data_01
  from MainTable (nolock)
       left join ufd as UfdCase (nolock) on UfdCase.keyid = MainTable.keyid and UfdCase.table_code = 'case'
       left join ufd as UfdAppe (nolock) on UfdAppe.keyid = MainTable.keyid and UfdAppe.table_code = 'appe'
```

But I could also do this:

```
select case when ufd.table_code = 'case' then ufd.user_field_data_01 else '' end,
       case when ufd.table_code = 'appe' then ufd.user_field_data_01 else '' end
  from MainTable (nolock)
       left join ufd (nolock) on ufd.keyid = MainTable.keyid
```

This is greatly simplified (I have some pretty large case statements that could get larger if I have to check to see which table_code it is).  To me the first one is more readable.  I'm just curious which is more efficient, gives better performance?  Or are they equal enough that id doesn't matter?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the second one is better than first one.

Comment: The best way to really find out is test. A `CASE` expression may well be faster, as it doesn't need to parse the table a further time, but it also depends on your indexes. On a unrelated note, what is your reason for using `NOLOCK`? You do *know* what that does, right?

Comment: Yeah a greatly simplified query with no details about table structure or indexes is impossible to answer. And to expand on the notion of the NOLOCK hint being a bad idea you might want to take a peek at this. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Honestly, I was not aware of all of those issues with NOLOCK.  I knew some and use it when those are ok.  However, I'm now rethinking all of that.  Thanks very much for the link, that was very informative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not exactly equivalent.

Presumably, you have more than one row in `ufd` for each master key.  So, the equivalent for the first query would be:

```
select mt.keyid,
       max(case when ufd.table_code = 'case' then ufd.user_field_data_01 end),
       max(case when ufd.table_code = 'appe' then ufd.user_field_data_01 end)
from MainTable mt left join
     ufd
     on ufd.keyid = mt.keyid
where ufd.table_code in ('case', 'appe')
group by mt.keyid;
```

(Well, I added the key.)

I assume that this is the actual result set that you want.

Which is better?  I typically go the conditional aggregation route, because it is easier to extend for more columns and more complex logic.  Additional columns add very little additional overhead.

From a performance perspective, you need to test.  But with the right indexes, I wouldn't be surprised if the second method were better -- for two columns.  With additional columns or more complex logic, the conditional aggregation method is more consistent performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts and info!  Yes, I do need to test it and right now my queries are all running under 5 seconds so I'm not too concerned.  But I'll test it for those queries that end up taking longer - any way I can make it faster for the users.  :)